# How to multiply values in a dictionary by an integer given in the parameter?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to multiply scores inside the dictionary by an integer given in the parameter for a specific key. If the integer is not for the key then I want to return the scores as is.

```
def main():
    scores ={'Bella': [2, 8, 3], 'Jack'= [8, 9, 7, 4]}
    multiply_scores(scores, 'Bella', 3)
    print(scores['Bella'])
    print(scores['Jack'])
```

Expected output:

```
[6, 24, 9]
[8, 9, 7, 4]
```

My current output is:

```
[6, 24, 9]
[24, 27, 21, 12]
```

How can I fix my code to get the expected output:

```
def multiply_scores(scores, name, number):
    for values in scores.values():
        for index in range(0,len(values)):
            values[index] = round((values[index] * number))
    return values
```

Comment: `'Jack'=` is invalid syntax and `score` is not defined

Comment: The problem is that you're not using the key (`name`) at all. Do you know how to get and set values in a dict based on the key?

Comment: Your script has a couple of bugs in it. Make sure you've run what you post, it reduces confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You've made this harder than it needs to be.

```
def multiply_scores(scores, name, number):
    scores[name] = [i*number for i in scores[name]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the name is a key in the dictionary, use it to get the list. When you assign to a slice object, the list will iterate the thing on the right, which is a convenient way to do an in-place modification of the list.

```
def multiply_scores(scores, name, number):
    lst= scores[name]
    lst[:] = (v * number for v  in lst)

def main():
    scores ={'Bella': [2, 8, 3], 'Jack':[8, 9, 7, 4]}
    multiply_scores(scores, 'Bella', 3)
    print(scores['Bella'])
    print(scores['Jack'])

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get list from your dictionary and update that list.
and before that check if the keys in the dictionary.

```
def multiply_scores(scores, name, number):
    try:
        scores[name] = [i * number for i in scores[name]]
        return scores
    except KeyError:
        return scores
```